# Return an oracle column as timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I'm in coldfusion working with data from an sql table, and using a query of queries to join the sql data to some data from an oracle database. Unfortunately, I need to order them by date, and the oracle table has two columns - DRWR_DATE which is of type DATE and TIME which is of type VARCHAR2. The two columns put into a string read `17-JUN-03 16:35:18` or something similar. I need to return these two columns as a TIMESTAMP so I can use query of queries to sort them.

Also, I think I read that a date column holds the time in Oracle anyway? I don't have much experience with Oracle so I am unsure how best to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  to_timestamp(
              to_char( drwr_date,'dd-mon-yy') ||' '|| time
              , 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss'
        ) 
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `TO_TIMESTAMP` function:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('17-JUN-03 16:35:18', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: That does work, I was completely thrown off by the DATE column type. It must still store the time? Is the DATE same as sql DATETIME?

Comment: How does this help if one of the columns is a date and the other a varchar?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg don't get yourself confused asking this here. Read the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT513

Comment: Date does still store a time.  Even though not really needed for your question but something to keep in mind is you can truncate off the date.  SELECT TRUNC(drwr_date) FROM YOUR_TABLE;  Just something to remember for possible future date comparisons because forgetting that a time is in there can create some people some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you can try converting the column to date as the following:

```
TO_DATE(column,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

The first parameter takes your column and the second parameter specifies the date format that is used

Comment: The column is already a date... how does converting it to a date help?

Comment: he said the column is the combination of a DATE column and a VARCHAR column, so I guess the combination is a VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

If all you have to do is order by date, all you need is an order by clause.

```
order by drwr_date, time
```

You don't have to cast these to anything, unless you need to do so for another reason.  Remember that a date datatype is essentially a floating point number.  This, "17-JUN-03" is simply how your client is displaying it.

Comment: The data came from sql and oracle and it was coldfusion throwing the error - So it may be that my problem was coldfusion specific.

Comment: Just so you know, the term "sql" is ambiguous in the context you are trying to use it.  Technically, it's a programming language, not a database engine.  Those who attempt to use it to specify a database engine might mean sql server, mysql, or postgresql.

Comment: Yeah I guess I just get used to referring to Microsoft SQL server as sql